# android how do I restart my activity in a view?

Tags: android

I have an app, that have the activity(called MyFirstActivity) and the onCreate is something like this:

```
    MyView view;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.game_sound_space);


            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myMain);

            view = new MyView(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout); 

            layout.addView(view, 0); // add view to the layout
    }
```

the view is something like this(this is the constructor):

```
Context context;//I need to do context global for using in other methods
public MyView(Context context,SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
              RelativeLayout parentLayout) {
        super(context);

this.context = context;

}
```

obviously in the activity on the onResume method I start the view:

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        view.loadGame();
    }
```

the loadGame() is on my view, it works perfect, but in some point on my view I wish to restart again the whole game, I have used:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),MyFirstActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
```

but I have the suspicious that this is not the correct way to restart(and that is starting to go wrong)
also using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

its impossible because I'm in a view and context.finish() does not work(does not exist)

so how do I restart the firstActivity (MyFirstActivity) in order to restart the view and with this the game?? need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle it your logic to restart your view. You can either do a [removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) with some animation and then later do a `addView` with `loadGame`. This will give a restart effect.